# Summarizing Excel with multiple columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot, office365, countif

I have Excel data in a table with a single row, and multiple values in two categories, and I want to summarize the two categories.

Input data:

[image]

| Recipe | Meal |  | Ingredients |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Plum pie | Coffee | Dessert | Plums | Sugar | Eggs |
| Plum jam | Breakfast | Coffee | Plums | Sugar |  |
| Fried eggs | Breakfast | Lunch | Eggs |  |  |
| Pancakes | Breakfast | Dessert | Eggs | Flour | Milk |

Desired output:

[image]

|  | Eggs | Flour | Milk | Plums | Sugar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Breakfast | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Coffee | 1 |  |  | 2 | 2 |
| Lunch | 1 |  |  |  |  |
| Dessert | 1 | 1 | 1 |  |  |

Of course restructuring the input data and summarizing via a Pivot table or Countif is a solution, but not a practical possibility due to the source of the data.

Can anybody help with an intelligent solution (and apologies for the table pictures - can anybody help pasting tables other than as pictures - I solved the tables problem partially via https://tableconvert.com/excel-to-markdown but alas - no colors)

Thanks,
Anders

Comment: Please use [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) to insert your data. What is your Excel version?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables for how to add your data in Markdown Table form

Comment: Excel 365/Enterprise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite verbose and an high percentage of lambda, but dynamic enough for you to only enter two variables at the start:

[image]

Formula in `I2`

```
=LET(meals,B2:C5,ingredients,D2:F5,uq_ing,SORT(UNIQUE(TOROW(ingredients,1),1),,,1),REDUCE(HSTACK("",uq_ing),SORT(UNIQUE(TOCOL(meals,1))),LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,HSTACK(y,MAP(uq_ing,LAMBDA(z,SUM(BYROW(meals,LAMBDA(v,SUM(N(v=y))))*BYROW(ingredients,LAMBDA(w,SUM(N(w=z))))))))))))
```

Comment: Looking at my results and your desired output, they do differ, but I'm wondering if perhaps you got it wrong since for example 'Dessert' appears twice and if I had to manually look at the ingredients needed..... it would be the same as the above results.

Comment: Thanks JvdV and Tom - works as it should, except you were unable to replicate my counting error, but that is acceptable :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
=LET(
    meal, B2:C5,
    ing, D2:F5,
    uMeal, UNIQUE(TOCOL(meal)),
    uIng, UNIQUE(TOCOL(ing, 1)),
    arr, MAKEARRAY(
        ROWS(uMeal),
        ROWS(uIng),
        LAMBDA(row, col,
            SUM(
                BYROW(meal, LAMBDA(r, SUM(--(r = INDEX(uMeal, row))))) *
                    BYROW(ing, LAMBDA(r, SUM(--(r = INDEX(uIng, col)))))
            )
        )
    ),
    VSTACK(HSTACK("", TRANSPOSE(uIng)), HSTACK(uMeal, arr))
)
```

Probably very similar to @JvdV's answer, but at least you can check the results against each other.

[image]